# Is there an electric field due to current?

Tags: electromagnetism

Is there any electric field associated with current? If yes, then charge particle passing through magnetic field due to current should also experience electric force along with magnetic force.

Comment: I would say that the current *exists* because of the electric field of the other charges. Any charge sets up an electric field - moving in a current or stationary.

Comment: Could you tell me upon which factors that force depend?

Comment: Upon which factors the electric force depends? $$F_{electric}=Eq$$where $E$ is field strenght and $q$ is charge.

Comment: @Steeven: But there is an extra electric-field-component due to acceleration/current-change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a charge density $\varrho$ and a current density $\vec{j}$ the EM-potentials in [Lorenz-gauge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retarded_potential#Potentials_in_the_Lorenz_gauge) are given by:

\begin{align}
   \varphi(\vec{r},t) & = \frac{1}{4\cdot\pi\cdot\epsilon_0} \int \frac{\varrho(\vec{r}\ ', t_r)}{|\vec{r} - \vec{r}\ '|} d^3r' \\
   \vec{A}(\vec{r},t) & = \frac{\mu_0}{4\cdot\pi} \int \frac{\vec{j}(\vec{r}\ ', t_r)}{|\vec{r} - \vec{r}\ '|} d^3r'
\end{align}
with $t_r = t - \frac{|\vec{r} - \vec{r}\ '|}{c} $. The electric field is given by:
\begin{align}
   E & = -\nabla \varphi - \frac{\partial \vec{A}}{\partial t} \\
     & = -\nabla \varphi - \frac{\mu_0}{4\cdot\pi} \int \frac{\partial\vec{j}(\vec{r}\ ', t_r)}{\partial t_r} \cdot \frac{1}{|\vec{r} - \vec{r}\ '|} d^3r'
\end{align}
The first term has nothing to do with the current (it's just the usuall electrostatic term originating form the charges), while the second is zero if the current is stationary. So yes, for a non-stationary (time-varying) current, there may also be an **"additional"** electric field, that originates from **current-change** only.

This is like: If charges are moving, there is a magnetic-field. If they have an acceleration $\ne 0$, there is also an extra electric-field-component due to this acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

See, e.g., http://www.astrophysik.uni-kiel.de/~hhaertel/PUB/voltage_IRL.pdf : a power source (say, a battery) creates surface charges on the conductor, and these surface charges create electric field.